# Paste the first column at the bottom line of the editing file

Tags: external-command

Here is the file `sample.txt` i am editing in vim:

```
   col11  col12
   col21  col22
```

`awk` can cut the first column from `sample.txt`:

```
awk '{print $1}' sample.txt
```

In vim it is `:!awk '{print $1}' %`,how can i  paste the selected first column at the end of file,to get the following content?More concretely how to copy the `awk`'s result at the bottom line in vim's ex mode?

```
   col11  col12
   col21  col22
   col11   
   col21
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So two sub-questions...

1. How do I have an Ex command operate at the end of the buffer?
2. How do I read in the output of a shell command?

The answers are [`:$`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#:$) and [`:r[ead] !{cmd}`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#:r!), respectively. The former is a line range<sup>1</sup> which should always come first. That gives us:

`:$r !awk ...`

<sub>1. Yes, "range", even though `$` specifies a single line. Per [`:h cmdline-ranges`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-ranges) a range "consists of *one or more* line specifiers".</sub>

---

Just for FYI fun and possibly a dash of edification for some there's also a very slightly, subtly different form that does the same thing. Since `:read`, when it isn't preceded by a line range, adds the read-in text below the cursor line you could also do:

`:$ | :r !awk ...`

`:$` alone moves the cursor to the end of the buffer and that's followed by another command (care of `|` which allows multiple commands on one line): the range-less `:read`. Note: the `:` preceding `r` is optional here; I added it to make it clear that it's a second, separate Ex command.